# Display only some parts of website in Chrome custom tabs

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I want to know if I can block some elements of a website in custom tabs. I know you can do it in WebView by running javascript like:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:my javascript");
}
```

What is the way to do this in Chrome custom tabs?

Answer (score 2):

You can't inject javascript in Chrome custom tabs.